# Use diff and ignore empty directories

Tags: diff

This is my tree

```
├── test
│   ├── dir1
│   └── dir2
│       ├── file
│       └── file2
└── test2
    └── dir2
        ├── file
        └── file2
```

I use `diff`: `diff -r test/ test2/`

```
Only in test: dir1
```

So the only difference is that there is an empty directory (`dir1`) in in `test/` which does not exist in `test2/`.

I want to ignore empty directories as a difference. So I want in this case that diff tells me that the content of `test/` is the same as the content of `test2/`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found an way of doing it but i'm not really happy with it.

`diff` can be told to exclude files matching a pattern. Sadly the pattern only works on filename, so my **solution may exclude more directories (and files too) than expected**.

Here it is, fwiw :

```
diff $(find test -empty -type d -exec sh -c 'echo -n "-x $(basename $1) "' _ {} \;) -r test/ test2/
```

I added the following command

```
find test -empty -type d -exec sh -c 'echo -n "-x $(basename $1) "' _ {} \;)
```

which outputs the basename of every empty dir preceding by `diff`'s exclude  option *-x*. With your example tree, it would output : *-x dir1*